# Flash AS3 Software Synthesizer

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sound-synthesis

I've been looking for a software synthesizer in AS3 for quite some time now, but without any success. I'm trying to build a score editor / player in AS3 and I have managed to build (a very crude) one using the [SiON synthesizer](http://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/). However, it is not very fast and the sound quality is nothing to write home about either.

Can anybody suggest a good softsynth?
Also, can anyone direct me to a good opensource score (or tab) editor-cum-player?

Cheers,

Comment: something like http://code.google.com/p/standingwave/ ?

Comment: @www0z0k, I downloaded SW3 (before I asked this question) but haven't had a chance to check it out yet. I also haven't been able to find any documentation on SW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PopForge and/or AudioTool

- http://code.google.com/p/popforge/
- http://www.audiotool.com/app

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ...hence the suggestion of PopForge.